# How to change text in H1 tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to expand a h1 tag when clicked on.  I currently have the header set to be > Header Text.  Now if the header is expanded, I want to change the text to be ▼ Header Text.

How can I change the text from > Header Text to  ▼ Header Text on the click event?

```
    $(function () {
    $('.grid-container').hide();
    $(".grid-panel").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('div').hasClass('grid-panel')) {
            $(this).find('.grid-container').toggle();
        }
    });

    <div class='grid-panel'>
    <h1 id="h1sprc" runat="server">&gt; First Data To Show</h1>
    <div class='grid-container'>
        <telerik:RadGrid> </telerik>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using text for the right/down arrows? What about using a (for example) bootstrap icon?

Comment: @Snowmonkey - I currently am just using thte > symbold (shift period) I am open to other options

Comment: you might want to change the text of the h1 from `&#x2192; Header Text` to `&#x2193; Header Text` -- but which is the h1? Or just wrap the arrow bit in a span, and update that.

Comment: Please post your html so we know what we are dealing with

Comment: @Snowmonkey - see edit.  I addded i the h1 tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toggle()` jQuery for hide and show.

For changing the text you have to put some conditions to compare and then use `html()` jQuery to change the content.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grid-container').hide();
  $(".grid-panel").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.grid-container').toggle();
    if ($(this).find('span').html() == "&gt;")
      $(this).find('span').html("&or;")
    else
      $(this).find('span').html("&gt;");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='grid-panel'>
  <h1 id="h1sprc" runat="server"><span>&gt;</span> First Data To Show</h1>
</div>
<div class='grid-container'>
  Grid Container
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've added the glyphicon set, using a span to display the arrow and toggling its classes between down and right. Other than saving references, the `triggerEl.children("span")....` line is the only one I changed. Of course, I did include a reference to the glyphicon CSS.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grid-container').hide();
  $(".grid-panel").click(function(e) {
    let triggerEl = $(e.target),
        arrowSpan = triggerEl.children(".arrow-bit");
    
    if (triggerEl.closest('div').hasClass('grid-panel')) {
    // Find the arrow span, and toggle the
    //  arrow between down and right.
    // this is the only line I really changed.
   triggerEl.children("span").toggleClass("glyphicon-arrow-right").toggleClass("glyphicon-arrow-down");
      $(this).find('.grid-container').toggle();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='grid-panel'>
    <h1 id="h1sprc" runat="server"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span> First Data To Show</h1>
    <div class='grid-container'>
<p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.</p>

<p>Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```